# Local Notification on significant location change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, uilocalnotification

I am working on a prototype to notify user on a significant location change. When the app is closed/terminated, I send a Local Notification to notify the user. The notification works perfect, but, for **one time only**. Though I receive the location change in `didFinishLaunching:`, I am not getting the Local Notification. Below is my simple code.

In `ViewController` I register for notification.

```
#import "LocationViewController.h"

@interface LocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation LocationViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Registerimg for Motification
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
}
```

Below is my `didFinishLaunching:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");

    self.shareModel = [LocationShareModel sharedModel];
    self.shareModel.afterResume = NO;

    [self addApplicationStatusToPList:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"];

     UIAlertView * alert;

    //We have to make sure that the Background App Refresh is enable for the Location updates to work in the background.
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied){

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                          message:@"The app doesn't work without the Background App Refresh enabled. To turn it on, go to Settings > General > Background App Refresh"
                                         delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted){

        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                          message:@"The functions of this app are limited because the Background App Refresh is disable."
                                         delegate:nil
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    } else{

        // When there is a significant changes of the location,
        // The key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey will be returned from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
        // When the app is receiving the key, it must reinitiate the locationManager and get
        // the latest location updates

        // This UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key enables the location update even when
        // the app has been killed/terminated (Not in th background) by iOS or the user.

        if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
            NSLog(@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey");

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

            //Establish notification details
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
            notification.repeatInterval = 0;
            notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Success"];
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

            // This "afterResume" flag is just to show that he receiving location updates
            // are actually from the key "UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey"
            self.shareModel.afterResume = YES;

            self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
            self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.delegate = self;
            self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
            self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeOtherNavigation;

            if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
                [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }

            [self.shareModel.anotherLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

            [self addResumeLocationToPList];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I follow [this](http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended) tutorial for the location change and added my notification methods to it.

Where do I lag in getting notification on every significant location change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself after some investigation.

When the application is listening to significant location change and if the application is closed, when there is a location change, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called and I get the local notification as discussed in my question.

It means that the application is launched, but, not in the foreground.

For the next location changes, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will not get called, as, the application is already launched. So, the general delegate method, `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, `didUpdateLocations:` will get call for all location change there after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using iOS 8 or higher as a deployment target.
Did you add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in you info.plist? I don't see that in your tutorial and that's mandatory for Location libs.

Comment: I added requestAlwaysAuthorization in code and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in plist as well.

Comment: Try to use a LocationManager and see if you receive locations of your current position.